# Clicking css buttons in selenium

Tags: java, css, selenium, css-selectors, click

I'm working on a test case in Java and am using selenium to record a set of events and "replay" them to an app. The code is:

```
// *The app opens a new window*
// Get handle of the main window
        String mainWindowHnd = webDriver.getWindowHandle();
        // Get all open window handlers
        Set openWindows = webDriver.getWindowHandles();

    Iterator ite=openWindows.iterator();
    // Select the new windows (there are two that are open)
    while(ite.hasNext())
    {
        String popupHandle=ite.next().toString();
        if(!popupHandle.contains(mainWindowHnd))
        {
            webDriver.switchTo().window(popupHandle);
        }
    }

    WebElement liveId = webDriver.findElement(By.id("c_clogoc"));
```

The id of the last statement is valid but inaccessible due to a css banner that is shown when the new window is opened. Running selenium IDE gives the following events:

`Command` :: `Target`

click      css=a.close

How can I replay the command in Java so that the web driver closes the banner?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `findElement` by a CSS selector:

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("a.close")).click();
```